# Wordpress - How to make shipping price zero in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a condition where I want to make shipping price zero. Is there any predefined function for that? like we have a predefined function for making the cart empty,

```
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
```

Similarly is there any function to make shipping price zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [official documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/free-shipping/):

If free shipping is enabled customers will have access to free shipping on their orders. You can however specify a few conditions they must meet to be granted free shipping such as;

- Minimum order amount
- Coupon (Users will need to enter a valid free shipping coupon code to use this method. If a coupon is used, the minimum order amount will be ignored)
- You can also choose specific countries to which free shipping is allowed.

Further, the free shipping method has an is_available function which can be hooked into:

```
return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_' . $this->id . '_is_available', $is_available );
```

This means you can use `add_filter()` on `woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available` and return `true` or `false`.